How to use a completely different layout file for deeply nested child routes in NextJS app router?
Given this app router structure:
app/
 - layout.tsx        <-- root layout
 - page.tsx
 - (dashboard)
   - layout.tsx      <-- dashboard layout including a header and sidebar
   - page.tsx
   - [projectId]
      - page.tsx
      - [environment]
         - page.tsx       <---- On this page I do NOT want to have the header and the sidebar from the dasboard layout


On the [Environment] Page.tsx I would like to have a completely different kind of layout that does NOT include the header and the sidebar from the Dashboard layout.
How can I achieve this while keeping the DashboardLayout as a server component?
